# Should I make a taxonomy to organize data like this?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I want to organize data on my website the following way. I am not sure how it can be done. Do it need to make a custom post type or taxonomy to organize data like this.

Help and guidance will be appreciated.

```
home
- incubators
    - incubators name
        - incubated startup
        - incubated startup
        - incubated startup
        - incubated startup
        - incubated startup
        - incubated startup
    - incubators name
        - incubated startup
        - incubated startup
        - incubated startup
        - incubated startup
        - incubated startup
        - incubated startup
    - incubators name
        - incubated startup
        - incubated startup
        - incubated startup
        - incubated startup
        - incubated startup
        - incubated startup
```

Sample URLs = www.abc.com/incubators/ycombinator/airbnb

Sample URLs = www.abc.com/incubators/ycombinator/quora

Sample URLs = www.abc.com/incubators/ycombinator/springtees

as recommended by some of the members. I have made a taxonomy of incubators.

```
// Register Custom Taxonomy
function custom_taxonomy() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'                       => _x( 'Incubators', 'Taxonomy General Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'singular_name'              => _x( 'Incubator', 'Taxonomy Singular Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'menu_name'                  => __( 'Incubators', 'text_domain' ),
        'all_items'                  => __( 'All Incubators', 'text_domain' ),
        'parent_item'                => __( 'Parent Incubator', 'text_domain' ),
        'parent_item_colon'          => __( 'Parent Incubator:', 'text_domain' ),
        'new_item_name'              => __( 'New Incubator Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_new_item'               => __( 'Add New Incubator', 'text_domain' ),
        'edit_item'                  => __( 'Edit Incubator', 'text_domain' ),
        'update_item'                => __( 'Update Incubator', 'text_domain' ),
        'view_item'                  => __( 'View Incubator', 'text_domain' ),
        'separate_items_with_commas' => __( 'Separate items with commas', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_or_remove_items'        => __( 'Add or remove items', 'text_domain' ),
        'choose_from_most_used'      => __( 'Choose from the most used', 'text_domain' ),
        'popular_items'              => __( 'Popular Items', 'text_domain' ),
        'search_items'               => __( 'Search Items', 'text_domain' ),
        'not_found'                  => __( 'Not Found', 'text_domain' ),
        'no_terms'                   => __( 'No items', 'text_domain' ),
        'items_list'                 => __( 'Items list', 'text_domain' ),
        'items_list_navigation'      => __( 'Items list navigation', 'text_domain' ),
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels'                     => $labels,
        'hierarchical'               => true,
        'public'                     => true,
        'show_ui'                    => true,
        'show_admin_column'          => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'          => true,
        'show_tagcloud'              => true,
    );
    register_taxonomy( 'Incubator', array( 'post' ), $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'custom_taxonomy', 0 );
```

Now the issue is, I am seeing it like a category in the All Posts section. Where as, the Incubators archive section should have links to all incubators. And each incubator should have a separate details page. At each details page, there should be a list of incubated startups in the bottom.

Comment: Based on your outline I would recommend a custom post type for `incubated startup`' and the taxonomy would be incubators.  Each incubator's name would be a member of the taxonomy.

Comment: I have made a custom post type for incubators. Now, I am confused on how to attach startups to each incubator.

Comment: I agree with @jdm2112 - you have 1 parent **Incubators** ( which would be your archive page `has_archive => 'incubators'`. Your post type would be `incubated_startup` and your taxonomy would be `incubator_name` because 1 `incubator_name` has many `incubator_startup` posts.

Comment: I have created a custom taxonomy as Incubators. Now in that, I am getting the option to add incubator names as categories. But I want to show details of each incubator too. Not just names.

Comment: @jdm2112 - can you help me with the code? i am generating the code from here. https://generatewp.com/

Comment: Edit your question and add your code.  You will find many more community members will assist when there is concrete code to answer questions about.

Comment: It sounds like both should be custom post types if you need data associated to each, one is the parent of another.

Comment: @Milo but how can I attach both of them to each other?

Comment: you can store the association by saving the ID of a post as post meta data in the related post.

Answer (score 0):

As I see it, since "incubators" is a way for you to group "startups", "incubator" should be a taxonomy of a "startup" custom post type. Make sure, when you register your taxonomy, to specify the link between the two.

```
register_taxonomy( 'Incubator', array( 'startup' ), $args );
```

You can enter details to describe your incubator by entering data and having a custom template taxonomy-incubator.php (see the [template hierarchy schema](http://codex.wordpress.org/images/1/18/Template_Hierarchy.png) to understand which template gets loaded when).

Should you need to enter more info about an Incubator, there are plugins for that (if you only need a Taxonomy Image the [WPCustom Category Image](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wpcustom-category-image/) plugin is enough, otherwise look at [WP Types](http://wp-types.com) or [ACF](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/)).

Comment: What I want to achieve is - 

Incubators is an archive page with list of incubators and links to their details page. 

Each Incubator is a separate post page and below each incubator there is a list of startups incubated there. 

By clicking on any link, the details of that startups are opened.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to using a taxonomy is to use two different post types- Incubators and Incubated. We can relate the Incubated posts to their parent Incubator by saving the post ID of the parent in the child's post metadata.

### Step 1 - Register the post types

See code comments for details.

```
// add parent and child post types
// set desired slugs using placeholder
add_action( 'init', 'wpd_post_types' );
function wpd_post_types() {
    // add the parent slug placeholder rewrite tag
    add_rewrite_tag( '%wpd_parent_slug%', '([^&]+)' );

    // arguments for Incubators (parent)
    // slug and archive are both just 'incubators'
    // feed and page rewrites disabled
    $parent_args = array(
        'public' => true,
        'label'  => 'Incubators',
        'rewrite' => array(
            'slug' => 'incubators',
            'with_front' => false,
            'feeds' => false,
            'pages' => false
        ),
        'has_archive' => 'incubators'
    );
    register_post_type( 'incubators', $parent_args );

    // arguments for Incubated (child)
    // slug contains parent slug placeholder
    // no archive for Incubated, the parent posts serve as their archive
    $child_args = array(
        'public' => true,
        'label'  => 'Incubated Startups',
        'rewrite' => array(
            'slug' => 'incubators/%wpd_parent_slug%',
            'with_front' => false,
            'feeds' => false,
            'pages' => false
        ),
        'has_archive' => false
    );
    register_post_type( 'incubated', $child_args );
}
```

### Step 2 - Oops, something is broken.

There's a problem with the rewrite rules generated for these post types- the parent attachment rules step on the child post rules. There are a couple of ways to fix this- one way would be to hook query parsing, check if it matches those attachment requests, and reset them to child post requests if that's what it's for. Another, much easier way is to get rid of those rules because maybe you don't need them. Alternate rules could be inserted to support attachments if desired.

```
// filter the array of all rewrite rules
// remove any that contain the parent post type and attachment
add_filter( 'rewrite_rules_array', 'wpd_remove_attachment_rewrites' );
function wpd_remove_attachment_rewrites( $rules ){
    foreach ( $rules as $rule => $rewrite ) {       
        if( strpos( $rewrite, 'attachment' ) !== false
            && strpos( $rule, 'incubators' ) !== false ) {
            unset( $rules[$rule] );
        }
    }
    return $rules;
}
```

### Step 3 - Filter permalink output for Incubated (child) posts

The child posts need to have their parent's slug in the URL whenever their permalink is output by the API, let's make that happen.

```
// filter post_type_link for child posts
// swap real parent slug for parent slug placeholder
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'wpd_cpt_permalinks', 1, 2 );
function wpd_cpt_permalinks( $post_link, $post ){
    // if this is an Incubated post
    if ( is_object( $post ) && $post->post_type == 'incubated' ){
        // get the parent ID saved in post meta
        // and swap that post's slug for the placeholder tag
        $parent_id = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_wpd_parent_id', true );
        $parent_slug = 'no-parent';
        if( '' != $parent_id ){
            $parent_slug = basename( get_permalink( $parent_id ) );
        }
        $post_link = str_replace( '%wpd_parent_slug%' , $parent_slug , $post_link );
    }
    return $post_link;
}
```

#### Caveat!

> There's nothing in this implementation that enforces a valid parent slug value in child post permalinks. In practice I don't think this is an issue. If you think it is, it is fixable by hooking into some stage of query parsing / querying and checking if the parent slug is valid and is a parent of the queried post, and forcing a 404 otherwise.

### Step 4 - Add a meta box to Incubated (child) posts for selecting a parent.

Generate a simple select list with names and IDs of all Incubator (parent) posts. Save the selected value in Incubated (child) post meta under the key `_wpd_parent_id`.

```
// Add the meta box
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'wpd_parent_metabox' );
function wpd_parent_metabox(){
    add_meta_box(
        'wpd_parent_metabox',
        'Parent Incubator',
        'wpd_parent_metabox_callback',
        'incubated',
        'side'
    );
}

// render the meta box
function wpd_parent_metabox_callback( $post, $metabox ) {

    // load the parent ID if it already exists
    $parent_id = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_wpd_parent_id', true );

    // add a nonce
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="wpd_parent_metabox_nonce" value="' . wp_create_nonce( 'wpd_parent_metabox_nonce' ) . '" />';

    // get all the Incabator (parent) posts and make a list of IDs / names
    // check previously saved value against each item's value
    echo '<select name="wpd_parent_id">';
    echo '<option value="" ' . selected( $parent_id, '' ) . '>None</option>';

    $parents = new WP_Query(
        array(
            'post_type' => 'incubators',
            'posts_per_page' => -1
        )
    );
    if( $parents->have_posts() ){
        foreach( $parents->posts as $parent ){
            echo '<option value="' . $parent->ID . '" ' . selected( $parent_id, $parent->ID ) . '>' . $parent->post_title . '</option>';
        }
    }
    echo '</select>';

}


// save meta box data
add_action( 'save_post', 'wpd_parent_metabox_save', 1, 2 );
function wpd_parent_metabox_save( $post_id, $post ) {

    // don't save if autosave, user doesn't have permission, or a revision
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return;

    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id )) return;

    if( 'revision' == $post->post_type ) return;

    // check nonce
    if( isset( $_POST['wpd_parent_metabox_nonce'] )
        && wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['wpd_parent_metabox_nonce'], 'wpd_parent_metabox_nonce' ) ){

        // save value or remove if none was selected
        if( isset( $_POST['wpd_parent_id'] )
            && '' != $_POST['wpd_parent_id'] ){
            update_post_meta( $post_id, '_wpd_parent_id', $_POST['wpd_parent_id'] );
        } else {
            delete_post_meta( $post_id, '_wpd_parent_id' );
        }

    }
}
```

OK, so far we have our post types and a way to relate children to parents. We can create each type of post and the links all work.

### Step 5 - Filter `the_content` and insert links to parent / children.

This will show you how to query for children or parent post(s). Parents will show a list of children, children will show a link to their parent.

```
// add links to post content
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpd_child_post_links_in_parent_content' );
function wpd_child_post_links_in_parent_content( $content ){

    // if this is one of our two post types
    if ( is_singular( array( 'incubators', 'incubated' ) ) ){

        $args = array();
        // set query args depending on what type this is
        if( 'incubators' == get_post_type() ){
            // meta query for any incubated posts (children) with this incubator ID
            $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'incubated',
                'posts_per_page' => -1,
                'meta_query' => array(
                    array(
                        'key' => '_wpd_parent_id',
                        'value' => get_the_ID()
                    )
                )
            );
        // this is a child post, check if it has a parent
        } elseif( $parent_id = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_wpd_parent_id', true ) ){
            // get the single parent from the ID stored in post meta
            $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'incubators',
                'posts_per_page' => 1,
                'p' => $parent_id
            );
        }

        if( !empty( $args ) ){
            // query and output the list if any posts were returned
            $related = new WP_Query( $args );
            if( $related->have_posts() ){
                $content .= '<ul>';
                foreach( $related->posts as $related_post ){
                    $content .= '<li><a href="' . get_permalink( $related_post ) . '">' . $related_post->post_title . '</a></li>';
                }
                $content .= '</ul>';
            }
        }

    }
    return $content;
}
```

Comment: I am reading the code and trying to digest it. I am not efficient in wordpress development. So I will follow your code and try to see if it works in my local machine. Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: It should work if you just paste everything into a plugin file or theme functions.php, and visit the permalinks settings page to flushes rewrites.